# How to split a text file in separate flowfiles by file contents in apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Apache NiFi 1.5.0 and I need to split incoming files based on their content, so not on byte or line count. There could even be rows that should be discarded.

Suppose this is the incoming file (`START` is the known split point, next lines may start with different words):

```
GARBAGE LINE 1234
START 53534
HIGHDATA 22
LOWDATA 885
START 1563632
HIGHDATA 252
HIGHDATA 20548
LOWDATA 240240
```

The first line must be discarded, then the content should be divided in two FlowFiles.

First Flowfile:

```
START 53534
HIGHDATA 22
LOWDATA 885
```

Second FlowFile:

```
START 1563632
HIGHDATA 252
HIGHDATA 20548
LOWDATA 240240
```

My idea is to apply a regular expression to each line of the FlowFile content and if it matches the current FlowFile is ended and sent out of the processor, then another FlowFile is created while the rest of the content is processed.

But I can't set up any component that would let me achieve that:

- `RouteText` works line per line, splitting too much
- `SplitText` splits based on row count or content length

The only processor that seems to do something is `SplitRecord` with a `GrokExtract` as reader, but then I can't get any writer to work by simply outputting plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SplitContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitContent/index.html) processor does what I'm looking for. It lets me specify a (text) sequence of bytes and produces a new FlowFile for each split sequence encountered.

Garbage rows can be excluded with a [RouteText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteText/index.html) processor, configured with a custom property that holds a regular expression matching the desired lines.